# Is Collections.shuffle(list); Fisher Yates Algorithm?

Tags: java, android-studio, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

```
List<TriviaQuestion> list;
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

is Collections.shuffle(list); can it be called Fisher Yates?

```
for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
            int j = r.nextInt(i+1);
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, well this code is for an array - what have you tried to translate it to support `List`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? `Collections.shuffle()` already uses Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Comment: And btw you cannot change/override it, because it's static method.